# Check if a string is alphanumeric without regular expressions

Tags: php

I want to check if a string is alpha-numeric and don't intend to use `Regex`. I have am getting the correct answer but somehow the program is throwing an error stating `undefined offset`. I have checked the array keys and seemingly they are fine.

```
$str="hello";
$arr=str_split($str);//convert a string to an array
$a=0;
$d=0;

for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++)
{
    if($arr[$i]>='a' && $arr[$i]<='z' || $arr[$i]>='A' && $arr[$i]<='Z')
    {
        $a=1;
    }
    elseif($arr[$i]>='0' && $arr[$i]<='9')
    {
        $d=1;
    }

}
if($a==1&&$d==1)
{
    echo "Alphanumeric";
}
else
{
    echo "Not alphanumeric";
}
```

Comment: `count` gives you the size of the array, and arrays start in 0, so either or you limit the for loop to `i < count($arr)` or you limit it to `i <= count($arr) -1`.

Comment: Also, how are you defining "alphanumeric," is "abc123!?#$" supposed to result in true?

Comment: I think thereis a logical error in your code, as @DaveS suggested. If the $a or $d variables are set to true, they won't be set to false later on. So even 'e5_)*&;[]()' would be returning Alphanumeric.

Comment: @Rafael The program works fine, plz try it. Alphanumeric means the string is supposed to have an alphabet and a number which are present in `e5_)*&;[]()`, therefore, technically it fall in the category of alphanumeric.

Comment: The logic is fine if that's the definition you're using. For some applications "alphanumeric" means ONLY a-z,A-Z,0-9 characters are in the string.   For that definition it would also be OK for a string to include only one of letters or numbers so "aaa", "111", "a2c" = alphanumeric, "a#2" = not alphanumeric.

Comment: Alphanumeric, by *definition* means either a letter or a number. Definitions beyond that are frequently used as: `You can use alphanumeric characters and underscores`. It comes with a sidenote explaining symbols that are not part of the definition but are accepted anyway. But that's not specifically my point. Any string, that might even be 99% symbols containing a single letter and a number will be considered alphanumeric. Which makes the "Not alphanumeric" case a very small exception.

Comment: Like, how come `a3&$#%*()_(_((*&@^~'¬¹²³5°` would be considered Alphanumeric and `&@^` would not?

Comment: @DaveS As per the program and my requirement, a string is supposed to have a number and an alphabet to be called an alphanumeric which is also widely used at many places. "aaa", "111"= Not Alphanumeric and this on the other hand "a#2" = Alphanumeric. Thanks for helping me out though.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for taking keen interest in the problem but my requirement is such that I can use symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array start at index zero, so the end ist `i<count`

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck at keys and never looked at the condition.Will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the `ctype_alnum ( string $text )`; function.

[ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

```
$str="hello";

if(ctype_alnum($str))
{
    echo "Alphanumeric";
}
else
{
    echo "Not alphanumeric";
}
```

Comment: No need to splt the string into an array here.  You can get rid of your entire loop.

Comment: I am a newbie and didn't have an idea about this function. Thanks again for letting me know it existed.

Comment: Yup no worries.  Good luck with the rest of your project.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `$i < count($arr)` or `$i <= count($arr) -1` as arrays start at 0 and having just `$i <= count($arr)` will result in an `undefined offset` error message.